# Distribution of numbers in everyday life

Tags: probability-distributions, integers

If you were to read tomorrow's newspaper it is intuitively more likely that the whole number 1 would appear more times than 643689443. Is there an expected distribution of numbers used in general?

I'm not sure how to express this in mathematical terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. Take a look at [Benford's Law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)

It only applies to the first digit in a number. But, as mentioned in the article, there are generalizations to longer strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but you might be interested in [Benfords Law](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law). Basically, smaller digits are more likely to appear than larger digits. $$P_1 \gt P_2 \gt P_3 \gt P_4 \gt P_5 \gt P_6 \gt P_7 \gt P_8 \gt P_9$$